# Unity ubuntu maximize on play not working

Tags: unity-game-engine, editor

Does anyone know if this is bug in Unity version 5.4.1f1 I am not able to to use the Maximize on Play feature in the editor. I have to manually maximize then play for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone know if this is bug in Unity version 5.4.1f1?

Yes, it is a bug. You need to vote for this bug [here](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/linux-editor-maximize-on-play-doesnt-expand-the-game-window) and file for a new bug report. This will let Unity know that so many people are having this problem.

I do suggest that you update your GPU driver. This will likely fix it temporary.